# rate of divergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, rate-of-convergence

I have a sequence defined as $\exp((\ln n)^{2})$. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, this sequence diverges.

What can I say about its rate of divergence? It is faster than any polynomial rate in $n$, but is there a better, more informative expression for it?

Similary, if the sequence were $\exp((\ln n)^{1/2})$. This should be slower than any polynomial rate, but again is there more to be said about this sequence?

Comment: Note that we have$$e^{(\ln{(n)})^2}=n^{\ln{(n)}}$$

Comment: fully agree (and thank you) - but does this sequence have a special name?

Answer (score 2):

$\exp((\ln n)^{2})$ is an example of **quasipolynomial growth**. This grows faster than polynomial but not as fast as exponential.

The general quasipolynomial form is $\exp(f(\ln n))$ for some polynomial $f(x)$.

But for $\exp((\ln n)^{1/2})$ you get **sublinear growth** because this is $o(n)$. But it's not as good as polylogarithmic growth which takes a form $f(\ln n)$ for a polynomial $f(x)$.

You can read more on the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity